# Unknown SqlResultSetMapping

Tags: java, multiple-databases, sqlresultsetmapping

I've been sitting here for long to solve this problem.
(I can't show a lot of code because it is corporate secret so here will be parts of it or just examples)

I have my project connected to 2 databases, with `DataSource`

Let's say I have database `employeedb` where my entities annotated with `@SqlResultMapping`

Before I connected second database `usersdb` everything worked perfectly, but now im' getting this

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [WalletMapping]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setResultSetMapping(NativeQueryImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1079) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at kg.megacom.antifraud.megapay.service.impl.WalletServiceImpl.getSusWallet(WalletServiceImpl.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at kg.megacom.antifraud.controller.WalletController.getWallet(WalletController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

So here is this entity:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "WalletMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Wallet.class,
                        columns = {

                                @ColumnResult(name = "count", type = Long.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "created_dt", type = Date.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "login", type = String.class)

                        })

        } )

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Wallet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long count;
    private Date created_dt;
    private String login;
    private Status status_marker;
//forgot to add my constructor in the question
    public Wallet() {
    }

    public Wallet(Long count, Date created_dt, String login) {
        this.count = count;
        this.created_dt = created_dt;
        this.login = login;

    }
}
```

And my configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "employeeEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "employeeTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "com.example.employee"})
public class MegapayDbConnect {

    @Value("${spring.employee.jpa.show-sql}")
    private String auto;

    @Value("${spring.employee.jpa.database-platform}")
    private String dialect;


    @Bean(name = "employeeDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.employee.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "employeeEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("employeeDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.example.employee.models.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("Megapay")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "employeeTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("employeeEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
```

I used `EntityManager` to extract results of my query, but it prints stacktrace above.

Answering questions in advance:

1.No, I can't use JpaRepository because it needs ID, but my query doesn't

2.I googled my problems, couldn't find solutions, so do not send me there pls

So my question is **what should I do? Maybe you have advices how to connect second DB in other way? Or extract result from query without ID but using JPA?**

Comment: Please add the query in your question description

Comment: @mystery there is nothing wrong with query, problem is when I connected second database, I got this exception

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem with your SQL mapping with the result set
Check which column you want in the query.
Also, you can add a constructor to the Wallet class along with a getter setter.
The constructor should have all the columns you want in the query

Comment: actually I have required constructor, just forgot to add in the question. Problem is I'm getting the same exception as I forgot ```@Entity```, but as you can see I have my Entity annotation